# Unicode escape sequence for identifiers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Below declaration works,

```
var \u0061 =2; // a  = 2;
```

But below declaration give an error,

```
var \u00A5 = 2; // suppose to be ¥ = 2;
```

code point `0xA5` is in BMP plane, Why this error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your escape sequence, which is fine. It's just that `¥` is not a valid identifier, in contrast to `a`. An [identifier](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-names-and-keywords) needs to start with `$`, `_`, "*any Unicode code point with the Unicode property “ID_Start”*", or an escape sequence for one of the previous. [¥](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A5/index.htm), being a currency symbol, is not such character.

Comment: `var ヴァリアブル = "変量"` has valid identifier, but what is wrong with the identifier in `var ¥ = 2;`?

Comment: @overexchange: As I said, currency symbols are not a valid identier start. [The Katakana ヴ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/30f4/index.htm) in contrast is one.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is equivalent to:

```
var a = 2;
var ¥ = 2;
```

`¥` is not a valid character for a variable in JavaScript. See [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)